# Asp.Net MVC - Create a route that match everything but some strings

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, routes

I want to create a Mvc route that match every string, but all those ones that contains some values, for instance, I have this route:

```
        context.MapRoute(
            "Users_Bootstrap",
            "{ulrPrefix}/{*catchall}",
            new { controller = "Start", action = "Index" },
            namespaces: new[] { "Fanapo.Web.Areas.Users.Controllers" },
            constraints: new { }
        );
```

I want this route doesn't match any string that `urlPrefix` parameter be `Account` or `Admin` or `...`

Something like this: `ulrPrefix NOT IN [Account, Admin, ...]`

I think this should be solved using regular expresions, hope `IRouteConstraint` be the last option. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved using route constrains, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4416462/1655482)

```
public class NotInRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly string _notInString;

    public NotInRouteConstraint(string notInString)
    {
        _notInString = notInString;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values,
        RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_notInString))
            return true;

        var notList = _notInString.Split('|').Select(s => s.Trim().ToLower()).ToList();

        var value = values[parameterName] as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return !notList.Contains(value.ToLower());
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

The usage code:

```
//this is in another area
        context.MapRoute(
            "Users_Bootstrap",
            "{ulrPrefix}/{*catchall}",
            new { controller = "Start", action = "Index" },
            constraints: new { ulrPrefix = new NotInRouteConstraint(RouteConfig.ReservedUrlPrefix.JoinStrings("|")) }
        );
```

Hope there is another nicer solution. Thanks.

---

EDIT

---

A bit more faster:

```
public class NotInRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<string> _notInString;

    public NotInRouteConstraint(IEnumerable<string> notInString)
    {
        _notInString = notInString;
    }

    public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values,
        RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {
        if (_notInString == null)
            return true;

        var value = values[parameterName] as string;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
        {
            return !_notInString.Contains(value.ToLower());
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

AND

```
context.MapRoute(
            "Users_Bootstrap",
            "{ulrPrefix}/{*catchall}",
            new { controller = "Start", action = "Index" },
            constraints: new { ulrPrefix = new NotInRouteConstraint(RouteConfig.ReservedUrlPrefix.Select(s=>s.Trim().ToLower())) }
        );
```